# A static row in an HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a file listing a la windows explorer in HTML/Javascript. As such, I'd like the first row of the table, which contains the headings for all the columns, to be visible even when the columns are scrolled.

I've tried a few options involving placing the headings in a separate table, but all have failed for primarily one reason - when the file list is scrolled horizontally, the headings table does not scroll with it.

Hence, I'm essentially looking for an element linked to another in such a way that it scrolls with the other horizontally, but not vertically.

I realize many will think I should be using css and not tables, but this is moot as even using css I can't solve the problem of wanting the header bar to scroll with the files horizontally, but not vertically.

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think [this](http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html) might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to use Javascript. Hook to the onScroll event of both scrollable elements, and on the event update the scrollLeft property of both elements.

```
    var tableHeader = document.getElementById('tableHeader');
    var tableBody = document.getElementById('tableBody');

    function updateTableBody(e){
        tableBody = tableHeader.scrollLeft;
    }

    function updateTableHeader(e){
        tableHeader = tableBody.scrollLeft;
    }    

    tableHeader.addEventListener('scroll', updateTableBody, false);
    tableBody.addEventListener('scroll', updateTableHeader, false);
```

Of course, this is not bulletproof and could be optimized, but it will give you and idea and hopefully a good start.

NOTE: Make sure both element have the same dimensions, otherwise, the scroll will have a weird offset.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this isn't available as a CSS-only solution. CSS has some features that theoretically *should* be capable of being used to scroll a TBODY, but browser support is far too inconsistent.

One solution not mentioned yet is the Ext JS library. It does a LOT more than just scrolled tables, and you'll have to review the licensing to see if it will work for you, but their grid object is the most robust rich-UI-like table replacement I've seen.